# Why setwidth to other then 1 makes my line disappear?

Tags: c++, qt

As the comment inside my snippet allready explains:

The code isn't working as expected for lines with pen set to `noneSelectedLine` where pens width is != 1.

```
scene = new QGraphicsScene();
Qt::PenStyle ePenStyl = Qt::DashLine;
selectedLine = new QPen(Qt::blue);
noneSelectedLine =  new QPen(Qt::red);
selectedLine->setWidth(2);
noneSelectedLine->setWidth(1); 
noneSelectedLine->setDashPattern(QVector<qreal>(ePenStyl));

/*If this line is a comment all is running as expected, but as soon as I 
set in the following line, all lines where the pen is set to 
noneSelectedLine they are not drawn (or at least not visible). What could 
be the reason for that?*/

//noneSelectedLine->setWidth(3); 

for (int indexI = 0; indexI < 5; indexI++)
{
    scene->addItem(&LineSet[indexI]);
}
```

What can be here the reason?
If some informations are missing in the snippet, let me know and I'll clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code. First of all, this overload of vector constructor `QVector<qreal>(something)` creates a vector of `qreal` with a size of `something` elements, each of which will be initialized with a default value.

Second, `Qt::DashLine` is an `enum` value which resolves to `2`, so the line `QVector<qreal>(ePenStyl)` creates a vector of 2 `qreal`s, the value of which would be 0.

Third, `setDashPattern` doesn't work the way you think it works. Here's a quote [from the doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpen.html#setDashPattern):

> Sets the dash pattern for this pen to the given pattern. This implicitly converts the style of the pen to Qt::CustomDashLine.
>
> The pattern must be specified as an even number of positive entries where the entries 1, 3, 5... are the dashes and 2, 4, 6... are the spaces.

I think what you wanted to do is

```
noneSelectedLine->setStyle( ePenStyl );
```

instead of

```
noneSelectedLine->setDashPattern(QVector<qreal>(ePenStyl));
```